# Qt Key Event not behaving similar to keyboard

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to programmatically send key board presses. This works for the tab key and others, but for the space it does not.

Code looks like this for Tab and Space:

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this->viewer, event);

QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this->viewer, event);
```

When I do the tab press programmatically it changes between buttons, but when I programmatically press space it does not press the button (it get greyed as it was pressed, but the screen does not change as it should). When i do press space on my keyboard the button gets pressed and the screen changes.

Any idea why the behavior is not the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to send KeyRelease event after sending KeyPress event. As shown here:

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this->viewer, event);
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Space, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this->viewer, event);
```